# A general solution for providing modular setting system

Tags: dynamic, configuration, module, hierarchical, setting

We are planing to provide a general setting(configuration) system for a single page web application base on asp.net and SqlServer , we need a dynamic modular setting(configuration) which it can apply settings in a hierarchical way for any part of any module for example consider we have a difaultCityCode for each user and if the user didn't provide the value for that it should be retrieved from the user's portal and if the portal either didn't have the value it should be retrieved from the highest level in the hierarchy called SystemSetting.
we need to know if there is a clean and reliable solution for such a system?

Best regards Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after saw  lot of systems.
All of them use dynamic system module but none of them didn't have a hierarchical method to save data.
Sometimes setting is not a value it's a list or etc, so I build o module to save and load value setting for any entity of my project and for some setting that i can't use this module I have to use any method.
And also for hierarchical problem I save setting hierarchical and then use them hierarchically.